# Stop knockout rebinding on element add

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout-2.0

I am binding an observableArray to a list.

Whenever I am adding few elements the list is getting updated.

But after I do it for few times, a script alert is coming to stop/continue with the running scripts.

I am just binding 50 rows each time (Id, Name pair).
I think ko is binding the list again and again.

Can it be stopped?
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to single-threaded nature of javascript. If there is a function that takes a lot of time to execute, the browser will warn the user whether to terminate it to prevent it from dominating browser's execution. In your case, I guess you're adding many rows using `push` function which causes DOM updates for every item and takes a lot of time. To optimize it, try `ko.utils.arrayPushAll`:

```
 var yourArray = ko.observableArray();    
 //assume yourArray here is your observableArray
 ko.utils.arrayPushAll(yourArray(), data);//data here is the array you need to add to yourArray 
 yourArray.valueHasMutated();//this line notifies the subscribers to update
```

This will ensure that subscribers to the observableArray (yourArray) **are only notified once rather than with each push**.

For more information, take a look at [this link](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/416)

In case you still have performance problem even though you have applied that approach. You could avoid this problem by breaking down the execution into many small pieces using `setTimeout`. Like this:

```
var yourArray = ko.observableArray(); 

var totalItem = data.length;
var itemPerExecution = 20; //process only 20 items in 1 execution
var processedItem = 0; 
setTimeout(function generateRows(){
      var smallData = data.slice(processedItem,itemPerExecution);
      ko.utils.arrayPushAll(yourArray(), smallData);
      yourArray.valueHasMutated();

      processedItem+=itemPerExecution;
      if (processedItem < totalItem ){
          setTimeout(generateRows,0);
      }
},0);
```

Comment: Yes I am following the same approach.
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function (valuesToPush) {
        var underlyingArray = this();
        this.valueWillMutate();
        ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
        this.valueHasMutated();
        return this;  //optional
    };

But still having performance hit. :(

Comment: @Deviprasad Das: if you still have performance problem even though you have applied that approach. You could avoid this problem by breaking down the execution into many small pieces using `setTimeout`.